# Background image is set for entire Fragment instead of inner lineatlayout

Tags: android, background-image, android-dialogfragment

The final result is full screen dialog fragment with a background image no buttons.

Although the images is set as background for inner layout "imageLayout"
I will set other layout inside "imageLayout" so I can not replace it with imageview

I created a custom dialog fragment with following xml code "fragment_bottom.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentBottomLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

and style code "styles.xml":

```
<resources>

    <color name="SemiWhite">#ccffffff</color>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>


        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/SemiWhite</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

The JAVA code file :

```
public class ImageDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private List pass = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static String TAG = "FullScreenDialog";

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


            // Get Fragment belonged Activity
            final FragmentActivity fragmentBelongActivity = getActivity();


            String image_path = null;
            if (getArguments() != null) {

                int sNextCharText = Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("sNextCharText"));
                image_path = getArguments().getString("sImagePath");

            }

            final LinearLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentBottomLinearLayout);

            LinearLayout imageLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            imageLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            imageLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            if (!image_path.isEmpty()) {
                // Convert image to
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapImage);
                imageLayout.setBackground(d);
            }

            PasswordOnlyImageConstruction(imageLayout, fragmentBelongActivity);
            layout.addView(imageLayout);

            LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            buttonLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            buttonLayouteConstruction(buttonLayout, getActivity());
            layout.addView(buttonLayout);


        }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
    }
private void buttonLayouteConstruction(LinearLayout imageLayout, FragmentActivity activity) {
    Button doneButton = new Button(activity);
    doneButton.setText("Done");
    doneButton.setEnabled(!pass.isEmpty());
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });

    Button cancelButton = new Button(activity);
    cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Dismiss DialogFragment
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your description correctly, but did you mean for `layout.setBackground(d);` to be `imageLayout.setBackground(d);`?

Comment: Right, I corrected the code.
>     imageLayout.setBackground(d);
Is acting like 
>     layout.setBackground(d);

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it still doing it? If so, how big is the image you're loading into it? Is it so big that it would fill its parent `LinearLayout`?

Comment: The dialog fragment show only image on whole fragment no buttons

yes, it's big but, previously I used an activity with two fragments and  similar core code was used in one of the two fragments and there was no problem

Comment: Well, that inner `LinearLayout` is going to wrap to the image's size, whatever that ends up being. If you want it a certain size, then set definite dimensions on it. I would mention, though, that a `View`'s background is scaled to fill in both directions. That is, the image will go edge to edge, no matter what the image's aspect ratio is. This might cause it to warp your image, if you don't set a size proportional to the original dimensions.